# What is the extent of Bartolomeo's Devil Fruit power?

Tags: one-piece

Bartolomeo has quite a strong Devil Fruit.
In the Colosseum...

> ...he could block every punch with his Barrier fruit. He was really bored in this fight and had no problems at all.
>
>  [image]
>
>  For your information, the "King Punch" he blocked from "The Fighting King" Elizabello II is said to be more powerful than a Yonko. [Elizabello II - Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Elizabello_II)

**So my question is, can he really block everything?**

Can it block beams, like the Slow-Slow Beam from Foxy, and shock waves, like what Whitebeard created with his Gura Gura Fruit?

Comment: the power of devil fruit depend on the strength of the devil fruit user. With this I really doubt that he can block Whitebeard attack. I don't know if it's beam from Foxy or Boa.

Comment: Actually i found this in the wiki about Elizabellos KING PUNCH "It is rumored that one of his punches could even overpower a Yonko."
-http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Elizabello_II

Comment: Whitebeard could break oceans, so I don't think he will have much trouble breaking a barrier though. Especially from a rookie, but other than that I think you will have to wait till next chapter to see the extend of his power.

Comment: I think this question has multiple answers, because one piece has proven anything can happen in terms of powers/ability and weaknesses.  For example Buggy while a joke character and definitely not the strongest by any means was impervious to Mihawk's slashes. Same with Magellan(poison) and Mr 3(wax/candle).  So he very well could probably block a direct shockwave from White Beard, but with that said, White Beard is very intelligent fighter and I'm sure he would just easily work around that by targeting the ground under him or something.

Comment: So far the barrier is unbreakable and can not be penetrated by anything that attack him. So for now there is a possibility that the barrier can block anything. And I think it's not opinion based question, he didn't ask if Bartolomeo can defeat Whitebeard, but simply asking if the barrier can block anything or not. This can be answered by some new chapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bari_Bari_no_Mi) claims it is unknown at this point whether the barriers have a damage limit and I agree on this. **There has been no proof yet of something that could damage the barriers.** So as of writing (chapter 788) it would seem that the barrier would indeed be indestructible.

The strongest things we have seen the barrier block are:

- King Elizabello II's King punch, which could allegedly take down an entire fortress. (chapter 709)
- Hakuba's slashes (chapter 773)
- Gladius' full body rupture (chapter 773)
- The Birdcage (chapter 788)
- Chinjao's Haki imbued drill (chapter 788)

The only **limitations** we have seen so far are:

- It cannot block sound (chapter 742)
- It has a surface area limit (chapter 754 and 757)
- Only one barrier can be produced at the same time. (chapter 773)

As of now it does not seem like he would be able to block the slowbeam from Foxy, as that would consist of pure waves similar to sound or light. On the other hand, the beam from Franky would probably be blocked. Similar to King Elizabello II's King punch, it also seems that he would be able to block Whitebeard's shock wave.

---

Additionally, Oda has answered this question himself on [the Volume 77, Chapter 773 SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_77#Chapter_773.2C_Page.C2.A0192), saying Bartolomeo's barriers are indeed limited to one at the time and have a maximum capacity of **50.000 Bari-Bari or 500 Pickle-Pori-Pori-Bari-Bari's**.

> **Reader**: Oda-san, hello~. About Bartolomeo, he said something about how his barriers have a limit or whatever, so how many Bari-Bari's worth is its maximum capacity?                                               P.N. Hoichael Jackson
>
> **Oda**: Great question. There is in fact a limit to the space his barriers can cover, as well as how many barriers he can put up at a time. He can only hold up one barrier at a time, and they say that this one barrier can cover up to 50 thousand Bari-Bari's!! Amazing! 1 Bari-Bari equates to roughly 100x that of 1 Bori-Bari-Bari, so in other words, his barrier capacity is just about 500 Pickle-Pori-Pori-Bari-Bari's.
>
> *(Translator's Note: Bari, Bori, and Pori are all Japanese sound effects that roughly translate to 'crunching'.)*

Comment: TL;DR: Damage limit is unknown if it even exists but more importantly it only generates in limited spaces

Comment: He can produce more than one but limited barriers at a time. Else the answer is good.

Comment: @abhishah901 My reference was indeed wrong, but Bartolomeo did mention that he could only produce one at a time in chapter 773 at the end of the fight with Gladius